# Книги по HTML

Tags: html, книги

Здравствуйте, подскажите книги по HTML, в которых от и до все рассказывается! Приведите примеры книг, которые вы читали сами! Буду очень признателен. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 4):

HTML не стоит целой книги.
Вот HTML + CSS - стоит.
А вообще:
http://htmlbook.ru/

Answer (score 0):

- Самоучитель HTML, Гончаров.
- HTML в действии, Моррис.
- HTML. Экспресс-курс, Петюшкин.
- HTML. Просто как дважды два, Рева.
- Использование HTML 4, Браун, Хоникатт.
- И так далее.

Берите любую, только проку нет. Когда-то тоже начинал учить HTML по книге и быстро понял, что только время теряю. Много воды, много того, о чем вообще можно не знать. А вот об актуальных вещах пишут мало. HTML можно выучить по справкам в интернете. А вот по CSS можно и книгу купить.

Answer (score 0):

Книга нужна! ...чтобы начать понимать HTML. А потом, после прочтения страниц 100-200 можно её выкинуть и переходить к сайтам и яндексу :)

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо учить специально html. Лично я посмотрел пару уроков. Понял синтаксис. А дальше выучивал теги по мере надобности.

- [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru) - хороший сайт.
- [html.manual.ru](http://html.manual.ru) - тоже неплохой.

html - это основа, но на ней не зацикливайтесь, учите потом  php и css.

Comment: css тоже учите по мере надобности.