# HTML Разметка сайта,или же, как с нулевыми знаниями сделать сайт :)

Tags: html, css

Вкратце, я полный профан в web-разработке, но обстоятельства сложились так, что мне нужно сверстать сайт, который сам же и нарисовал. Мой опыт в вебе, примерно 4 часа.

Суть проблемы:

Я пытаюсь понять, как сделать правильную разметку сайта, что бы сразу сделать её верной, не колхозной и адаптивной.

Вот как это должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Честно говоря, я даже не знаю как правильно задать вам вопрос, на второй картинке, я попытался передать то, что нужно исправить и понять как это вообще работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что есть сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Максимально колхозный код)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Если кто то будет править код, пожалуйста, напишите что именно вы изменили, почему, и зачем.

Также просьба к спецам, можете ли подсказать какие-нибудь адекватные и актуальные на 2020 год гайды, книги, вообще, откуда лучше всего черпать знания?

P.S.S: Прошу прощения, за столь банальные вопросы. Видимо, по мере проработки сайта, их будет очень много.

Comment: Вряд ли у вас сразу получится что-то срочное, правильная разметка и вёрстка приходит после миллиона ошибок

Comment: @Inventor Это не срочное. Тут наверное дело в энтузиазме. В любом случае, мне кажеться что для того, что бы учиться - нужно задавать много вопросов. Знакомых я бы хотел пощадить) т1001 глупый вопрос вряд ли кто то выдержит, а тут ребята вроде как отвечают по собственной воле

Comment: Раз уж 1001 вопрос, то лучше по очереди их задавать. 1 маленький шаг за 1 раз. В один пост их категорически нельзя умещать, плюс есть правила. [Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с ними, прежде, чем продолжать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Тогда погружение в мир веб-разработки станет максимально продуктивным и комфотным (еще и будет меньше минусов в карму на сайте). По книгам [здесь есть существующие вопросы, новые задавать не приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8301/Книги-по-html), в интернете полно всего. И не пренебрегайте знакомыми, они отнесутся с пониманием.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Принял, благодарю за информацию :)

Answer (score 0):

скачать Visual Studio Code — редактор исходного кода

посмотреть и за одно сверстать 2-3 шаблона как минимум

первая ссылка

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltMSrSis9ww&list=PLoq3Accf02PVdUqjqPdWMG4HbEZXlhICW&index=1

в этом курсе в 11 то ли в 12 видео используется jQuery вот с этого момента (мае мнение => хочеш по короткому но плохому пути посмотри и выучи jQuery если же по длинному но хорошему
просто повторяй за ним но не вдавайся глубоко в детали а когда сделаешь все то что написано внизу учи javaScript внизу есть ссылка на хороший ресурс  )
остальные сам поищи в youtube

для работы с psd можно использовать https://www.markupeasy.ru/ сам пользуюсь

ознакомся с методологией бэм

поищи видео или блог топ полезных плагинов для vscode облегчат жизнь

ознакомься с препроцессорами они нужны для сокращения написанного тобой кода на css я использую scss он древний но синтаксисом похож на css чем и нравится ps scss тоже что и sass отличие в отсутствии ; и {}

ознакомься с bootstrap многие любят это библиотека с готовыми кусочками кода
плюс в просторах интернета много чего готового для решения тех или иных зодачь

после этого верстку сделать сможеш

и потом начнется сложная часть
а именно javaScript(https://learn.javascript.ru/) , webpack , reack и тогдалие

Comment: `по короткому но плохому пути посмотри и выучи jQuery`, что плохого?)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 а что может быть хорошего в обертке? конечно упаковка конфеты  красивая но ты же  канфету сеш чтобы узнать вкус а не упаковку

Comment: @Armen Т.е по вашему все кто использует JQ, это плохие практиканты?) Не забываем для чего был придуман JQ, да, он сейчас не так актуален, но 99% что в работе с ним придётся встречаться не раз, и нужно хоть как то уметь с ним работать. К тому же для начинающего верстальщика это идеальный вариант, а с опытом он сам от него откажется в сторону других фреймворков и библиотек. Тем более если будет работать в команде, а если будет один, и только верстать, JQ будет за глаза

Comment: @Vearodev по моему все кто использует jQuery не зная js плохие практиканты... по двум причинам для меня

1. если столкнутся с не стандартной ситуацией где на jQuery нет готового решения или оно есть но надо кое что переделать тебе каюк

2.я был на собeседовании давно это было знал jQuery а задания(ооочень легкие задания были на чистом js) как вы думайте какой был результат?)))

Comment: @Vearodev и самое главное по вашему вот библиотек много как легче перейти с одной на другой знаю конкретную или зная то что связывает всех их

Comment: @Armen Большое спасибо за советы :) BrainsCloude смотрю, один из не многих кто говорит зачем и почему тот или иной тег нужен. Замечаю уже чуть прогрес, это конечно мотивирует, хотя время от времени из-за проблем появляеться желание приложиться чем-нибудь в монитор :>

Comment: @Armen Начинал когда то с JQ, и только набравшись опыта взялся за нативный JS, никак не помешало освоить angular,vue + backend(nest), с опытом смена языка или какого фреймворка не приносит никаких трудностей, даже если ты начинал с JQ, а начать с него, как ни крути проще, особенно верстальщику. Но, сколько людей, столько и мнений как говорится)

Comment: @tarasChopyk незачто был рад помочь да не то что связано конкретно с html,css хороших видео много не зацикливайся именно на нем вот с js и далее такой набор бесполезных кусочек мозаики что черт ногу сломает пока собирал сваю не знаю уже сколько всего пересмотрел