# Оцените верстку шаблона

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Начал заниматься версткой месяца 2 назад, поэтому не совсем разбираюсь, насколько правильно сделана верстка  и написан код, так что нужно, чтобы разбирающиеся люди помогли советом.
https://valeri-afk.github.io/Valeri-afk.github.io3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для section есть тег section

burger отталкивает то что сверху что не очень красиво + при закрытии css свойства теряются

якоря не работают

много чего работает за шет bootstrap это конечно верно но ты же хоть должен понимать как это все устроено

css имеет свойство cursor для визуального изменения значка мышки над тем или иным элементом

js напрочь отсутствует

а так вполне красивая и хорошая верстка с учетом методологии бем что верно

- можеш прочитать мой ответ тут может пригодится [HTML Разметка сайта,или же, как с нулевыми знаниями сделать сайт :)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201978/html-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82/1205183?noredirect=1#comment2104540_1205183)

хотя все это дело после изучения уже более продвинутых вешей надо будет сделать чуть по другому но это в будушем для 2 месяца как по мне хорошая верстка